# How do I run my discord.py bot without a hardcoded token?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been coding a discord bot for a while now, but have not figured out how to load my bot's token from somewhere else than by bot's python file. I'd want to use a text file (config.txt) for this, but anything of the sort works.

I have python 3.11.1 if that matters :D

```
imports blahblah
intents blahblah
...
client.run('token here')
```

Comment: I am not familair with discord's bot, but what prevents you from using the config file ? Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution on my own:

to your imports add

```
import json
```

add this code

```
with open("./config.json") as config:
  configData = json.load(config)
token = configData["Token"]
```

to the bottom

```
client.run(token)
```

this is the config.json

```
{"Token": "token here"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look into is environment variables.

Environments can be your local development environment, where you are obviously working at the moment, and there can be a staging environment, which is an environment that is like your production environment so you can see how your application behaves in a none local environment, which is important to know before you push it to production.

To use environment variables, the standard library in Python is, e.g. `os`

```
from os import getenv
```

With the `getenv` method, you can get the value of an environment variable, which needs to be populated in your current environment before you can call them.

Calling your token could look like this:

```
getenv("TOKEN")
```

This only can work if you before running something like

```
$ export TOKEN='token here'
```

in your Terminal.

Comment: There is no reason to capitalize ENV VARS or ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES. They are not acronyms.